# Tamarind Pulp Gritty

Tags: sauce, tamarind

After soaking and sieving the tamarind through a fine mesh strainer, the remaining pulp has some grit. It kinda ruined my dish. Wonder if there’s any method that would get rid of the grit, maybe a second sieving?

Comment: What do you mean by "grit"?  Like sand?

Comment: Are you asking for a method to get rid of the grit from your already prepared dish or the remaining pulp? Try lining the strainer with a cheesecloth to catch the bits from pulp next time.

Answer (score 1):

Ive had that before. Use a chinore to get a finer strain.

Answer (score 1):

Sieving through multiple layers of cotton cloth should do the job.